# Calling Stateless Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently learning React and i am working through 'The Road to React' by Robin Wieruch.

I've just refactored some code from a stateful to a functional stateless component like so:

```
function Search(props) {
  const { value, onChange, children } = props;
  return (
    <form>
      {children} <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      /> 
    </form>
  ); 
}
```

Gets Refactored to:

```
const Search = ({ value, onChange, children }) => {
  <form>
    {children} <input
    type="text"
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    />
  </form>
}
```

However nothing is rendering anymore. Are functional stateless components called the same was as stateful ones?

This is how I'm calling the Search component in the App class:

```
render() {
const { searchTerm, list }  = this.state;
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Search 
      value = { searchTerm }
      onChange = { this.onSearchChange }
    >
      Search
    </Search>
    <Table
      list = { list }
      pattern = { searchTerm }
      onDismiss = { this.onDismiss }
    />
  </div>
)
```

I'm not receiving an error at all, so i'm not getting much that's pointing me in the right direction, i'm hoping i'm just missing something silly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: arrow functions without braces use [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body), those with braces don't.

Comment: You need to return the element.

Comment: There is no such thing as "stateless"/"stateful" components anymore, the distinction lost its meaning when hooks were introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, it's a stateless function only as there's no state and it's not an class component either.

1st case is working correctly because it's returning the element with the `return` keyword.

2nd refactored case is also correct but you are not returning anything you need to return the element for it to be rendered.

### `return` example

```js
const func = () => {
    ... // any more calculations or code
    return ( // you are returning the element here
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
        )
    }
```

If there's no calculation or any additional code and you have to return only an element you can directly return it by using `(...)` instead of `{...}` as follows

```js
const func = () => ( // you are directly returning element
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
    )
```

PS: for more info you can check into [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough and clear answer  I purposely omitted the return keyword to make use of JS arrow functions implicit return, but obviously the inclusion of {} contradicts this. Thanks again!